# Windows 8.1 a ".\" in remote desktop gives current computer not remote computer

Tags: active-directory, remote-desktop, login, windows-8.1

We had some issues with our domain recently where we got the "trust relationship has failed" message on a server.

Now normally I could just login with the local admin to fix this, however I had upgraded to Windows 8.1 on my laptop and when I tried to use the ".\" domain to log in to the server using the local admin the domain resolved to the name of my laptop.

I could not use the actual server name because that looked it up in the active directory server and part of the issue was with the AD server.

Has the shortcut for the local computer changed in Windows 8.1?

Comment: It's a bug in windows 8.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'.\' would not work as that is 'your' computername. But you can use 'localhost'

```
localhost\localadminusername
```

Answer (score 5):

The RDP client is interpreting the ".\" locally and filling-in the name of the local computer rather than passing the ".\" literally to the remote computer. (I believe this changed around the time that the RDP security layer was abandoned in favor of SSL, but I can't give you a specific RDP client version number...)